# A little question on reverse proxies via mod_proxy on 16.04

Tags: proxy, authentication

I've run into a little bit of a hump and would like a bit of feedback from the community as I'm not sure how best to proceed. I have created a reverse proxy that allows the user to login into a website by just using a link, (authenticated IP address assigns the user to a subscription when using the reverse proxies URL)

I'd like to secure the proxy's URL so that it can only be accessed if the request has come from a particular referring URL which is behind a WordPress login area on another server.

I assume there is a configuration using the  control block that I can use?

Thank you in advance.